# SecurityError: Error #2152, cant switch to Full Screen mode

Tags: fullscreen, runtime-error, stagedisplaystate

Here my code:

```
    private function onSwitchFullScreen(event:Event):void{
        try {
            switch (VariablesGenerales._flash_stage.displayState) {
                case StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN:
                    // si on est déjà en FULL SCREEN, on se remet en normal
                    VariablesGenerales._flash_stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
                    trace(">>>>> SWITCH TO NORMAL SCREEN");
                    break;
                default:
                    // si on est pas en full screen, on passe en plein écran
                    VariablesGenerales._flash_stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
                    trace(">>>>> SWITCH TO FULL SCREEN");
                    break;
            }
        } catch (err:SecurityError) {
            // ignore
            trace(">>>>> FAIL TO SET FULLSCREEN");
        }
    }
```

as in other post of this problem, i have, Flash player 11.5+, i have set allowFullScreen mode to 'true' everywhere it is mentionned and i still cant turn my project in fullscreen, i get 'FAIL TO SET FULLSCREEN'.
I execute it in web, not in standalone.
Any idea? Thx!